# Accessing EC2 instance with DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an instance inside a VPC with DNS hostnames & DNS resolution enabled

Today, each instances I spawn get the hostname & Private IP DNS name as

```
ip-xx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal
```

The problem with this is everytime my instance is terminated and I have to replace it, the IP address is going to change. Other machines in the same VPC need a deterministic way to access this instance. e.g. by connecting to `mymasterinstance.dev`. Any idea how do I give an internal / private DNS for my instance?

Comment: private IP does not change. You are talking about public IP address?

Comment: I was talking about private IP as this is an internal usecase. We also didn't want to hardcode IP addresses because that would require changing hardcoded IP address when the instance is removed/replaced. In that case the private IP would change right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Private IP addresses** on Amazon EC2 instances **do not change**. Therefore, the other machines could simply reference the private IP address.

Alternatively, you can create a "Private hosted zone" in Amazon Route 53 and create an `A-Record` to associate a domain name (eg `mymasterinstance.dev`) with the **private IP address** of the instance.

The **public IP address** on an instance will change when the instance is Stopped and Started (but will *not* change when the instance is Rebooted). If you require a static public IP address, you can create an **Elastic IP Address** and associate it with the instance.

Comment: We don't need a public Elastic IP address. This is for a database cluster communication and is purely internal. The reason for not hardcoding IP address was because as you said, if an instance is revoked/stopped+start, then its IP is going to change and this would require a cluster wide config change

Comment: Your statement is incorrect. A **private IP address** will _never_ change on an Amazon EC2 instance. If an instance is Terminated, then it will lose the IP address, but the whole instance will disappear too.

Comment: I'm talking about scenario where after termination, I add back another instance. To brief you, our database has three masters and we want the agents to refer them in the config using `master1.local`, `master2.local`, `master3.local`. So, if `master3.local` instance got terminated and I decided to add a new master instance with DNS entry `master3.local` now pointing to the IP of the newly created instance. Had we hardcoded IP in our agent configurations then I'd have to modify their config files with the new instances IP. Does it make sense? Sorry for the lack of knowledge :)

Comment: I've come across private hosted zone. Do you think that's an overkill or perfectly fine solution for my problem

Comment: Feel free to Edit your Question to clarify what you are asking, to help future readers. There is a big difference between "termination" and "restart", hence the confusion we have been having.

Comment: You could have each instance assign itself a domain name under a Private Hosted Zone. The difficulty is thinking how each instance would know whether it is #1, 2 or 3. You can have the instances register themselves in Route 53 when they start-up. See: [Amazon Route 53: How to automatically update IP addresses without using Elastic IPs - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/amazon-route-53-how-to-automatically-update-ip-addresses-without-using-elastic-ips-h7o)

Answer (score 0):

Another perhaps simpler way to do this is to add a second IP address to your EC2 instance. When you terminate an instance, and add back a "replacement" instance, set its second IP address to what the terminated instance's second IP address was. Then you can do all of your referencing directly by IP address and you have full control over that second IP address. None of your configs needs to change.